# Showing minimality of this set without resorting to trichotomy

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867326/intersection-of-subset-of-a-natural-number-a-member-of-the-subset), which is to show that if $E$ is a nonempty subset of a natural number, then there is $k\in E$ such that for every $m\neq k$ in $E$, we have $k\in m$. I realized when showing that $\bigcap E$ is the "minimal" element that I had invoked a sort of trichotomy for ordering, which Halmos proves in the next chapter, so I suspect that Halmos expected the reader to prove this without the use of trichotomy.

What we have to show is
$$\left(m\in E \wedge m\ne \bigcap E \right)\implies \bigcap E \in m$$

But since $m \in E$, we know that $\bigcap E \subseteq m$. With trichotomy, we have 
$$n\subseteq m \iff n\in m \vee n=m \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\star)$$
so we have $\bigcap E\in m$ or $\bigcap E = m$, but the latter cannot happen so we obtain our result.

How can one do this without $(\star)$?

Comment: Or... you know, just prove the trichotomy property. It's about the same level of difficulty of the original problem.